# PostgreSQL full-text search drops rows from selection

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, database-indexes

Full-text search does not show any values by certain lexemes.

Though this code returns `true`:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('ispell_russian', description)
       @@ to_tsquery('ispell_russian', 'сам')
FROM callcenter.points_cardsservices
INNER JOIN callcenter.units ON recipientname = name
WHERE units.deptid = 5 
  AND id=366020;
```

result of the following selection is empty:

```
SELECT *
FROM callcenter.points_cardsservices
INNER JOIN callcenter.units ON recipientname = name
WHERE units.deptid = 5
  AND id=366020
  AND to_tsvector('ispell_russian', description)
      @@ to_tsquery('ispell_russian', 'сам');
```

The word I'm searching for used to be in a stopwords list. Can it cause this kind of problem? Also, the `to_tsvector('ispell_russian', description)` has an index on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never find a stopword, because that is filtered out before the search even begins.

But you say it *used* to be a stopword. If you changed the list of stopwords, you have changed the behavior of the `IMMUTABLE` (!) function `to_tsvector('ispell_russian', $1)` which you have used in an index.

If you change the behavior of an indexed immutable function, the index becomes corrupted. You will have to use `REINDEX INDEX` to rebuild the index.